# How to use ng-view in jsp pages for spring

Tags: angularjs, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, angularjs-ng-route

Trying to implement a user authentication with simple http session using angular and spring.
In `index.jsp`(my home page), a `ng-view` is being used.
But since the `$routeProvider` is not able to find the template from `templateUrl` for url `/login`(which i think is the reason for the ***errors***),
 hence only `index.jsp` page is getting rendered, and `ng-view` is not rendering and ***errors*** are also occuring.
Error and relevant codes are attached below along with a snapshot of my folder structure.

According to my limited knowledge, it is the way i am referring to my templates through `templateUrl` that is causing the **error**
[image]
**error snippet**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <-   $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html ng-app="PMApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>AUTH</title>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13"
src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-route.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/app.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/LoginController.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/MainController.js" />"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <h2>Hello World!Just trying the AUTHENTICATION . . .</h2>
         <div ng-view></div>              

    </body>
    </html>
```

**app.js**

```
var PMApp = {};
var App = angular.module('PMApp', ['ngRoute']);

App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   console.log("in routeprovider");
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {

            templateUrl: '/resources/views/loginLayout.html',

            controller: LoginController

        });
        $routeProvider.when('/main', {

            templateUrl: 'resources/views/mainLayout.html',

            controller: MainController

        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
     }]);

App.run(function($rootScope, $location) {

    // register listener to watch route changes

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {


        console.log("Routechanged sessionId="+$rootScope.SessionId);


         if ($rootScope.SessionId == '' || $rootScope.SessionId == null) {


             // no logged user, we should be going to #login

            if (next.templateUrl == "resources/views/loginLayout.html") {

                // already going to #login, no redirect needed

            } else {

                // not going to #login, we should redirect now

                $location.path("/login");

            }

        }

    });

});
```

Do ask for more details if required.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It was the version that was creating the problem. update it to 1.3.1 and everything works like a gem......